# How could I compare two data sets of X,Y coordinates to look for similarities?

Tags: javascript, authentication, comparison, coordinates, gesture-recognition

Pretty abstract question, but I'm conducting some research on gesture-based recognition. I've managed to get the gesture to be outputted into a series of X,Y coordinates that I can view as a scatter graph:

[image]

Here's my problem; I'm unsure on how to proceed. What is the best way to compare two data sets of X,Y coordinates and give a confidence percentage on how similar they are?

I'm currently using JavaScript and would ideally like to keep using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading about [handwriting recognition software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_recognition) it seems that the early phases such a recognising the strokes might be helpful. Decompose the gesture into a number of elements (lines or curves) then apply some matching algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of other questions that may be had here, for example: if a we have two identical gestures but one would be much slower than the other and take ten times the time, would they be considered similar?
Anyway, for starters I would look at each moment in time at the positions of the cursor in both gestures and determine the geometrical distance between them. Then you could compute a 'deviation' number of one gesture from the other, and if the number is big, then the gestures might not be similar. This could be a starting point.

Comment: great contribution, thanks. I'll look into deviation computation now.